# Devenv Command and password

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, ssis, azure-pipelines

I have a solution on visual studio 2017 that contains an ssis.
I am trying to build an automated build and deployment on vsts. 
I am using a devenv in a powershell script, but my problem is that my package is EncryptSensitiveWithPassword. and I don't know how to add the password to it.

this is what I used and it jumps a window asking for the password.

devenv "C:\Users\source\repos\LoadStageAreafromNap\LoadStageArea\LoadStageArea\LoadStageArea.sln" /build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Revised answer**

I re-created the scenario you described:

1. Created a new Integration Services project with corresponding solution.
2. Created a new SSIS package.
3. Added a Script Task to the package.
4. Added a password to the project

   1. Right click project.
   2. Select **Properties** from the context menu
   3. Set **ProtectionLevel** to "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword"
   4. Click ellipse (...)
   5. Enter password "test".
   6. Click **Ok**.
5. Add a password to the package.

   1. Right click Control Flow surface.
   2. Select **Properties** from the context menu.
   3. Set **ProtectionLevel** to "EncryptSensitiveWithPassword"
   4. Click the ellipse in the **PackagePassword** field.
   5. Enter password "test".
   6. Click **Ok**.
6. Select **Save All** from the **File** menu.

   **NOTE:** I have `devenv.exe` in my path.
7. Execute the following from a Powershell prompt:

   & devenv "$(pwd)\troubleshooting.sln" /Build Development /Project "$(pwd)\troubleshooting\troubleshooting.dtproj"

[image]

There is nothing you can do about this prompt. When you open the solution (or specific project) in Visual Studio. You get the same prompt. There is no way to pass this password as a command line devenv interface.

I found an [article](https://speaksql.wordpress.com/2013/06/07/a-journey-to-db-deployment-automaton-ssis-build-using-msbuild/) where the author uses MSBuild instead of DevEnv to build an SSIS project that has EncryptSensitiveWithPassword enabled. The article had two snippets I want to highlight:

> Building using devenv.exe works fine as long as your project’s
>   protection level is not EncryptSensitiveWithPassword, or
>   EncryptAllWithPassword.
>
> ...if you change the protection level to either
>   EncryptSensitiveWithPassword or EncryptAllWithPassword, a window will
>   pop up and ask you to enter the protection password. There’s no switch
>   that allows you to provide a password from the command line.

There is a lot going on. If you want to go this route, you have your work cut out for you.

Comment: thanks, but i am not sure what you are trying to do there. basically, i want to do automated deployment on vsts. and the solutions i found don't work, so I was planning to call devenv from a powershell script, but when I test it, i windows pops up asking for the password of the solution/package, so I just wanted to add it on the line.

Comment: I run the command and I got a box saying (I dont know how to add a picture)  <br/> project password sensitive data/.... <br/> it has a password box to add the project password <br/> once I did, i got in the powershell window the <br/> ------ Build started: Project: LoadStageArea, Configuration: Development ------
Build Build complete
Build started: SQL Server Integration Services project: Incremental ...
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Revised comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to build the project through [ssis-build tool](https://github.com/rtumaykin/ssis-build).